# Insert line of text to the top of a long text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, logging, text, insert

WebTrends analytics won't recognize log files without a header row with filed names. I have a bunch of logs I have to process (from January this year) that don't have this line. Some are close to 1GB in size.

How to I insert a line of text into a text file at the beginning, but make the script robust enough for massive file sizes?

Thank you all for your insights!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be better ways, but this is the fastest method I know of that will scale to files that size:

```
$header = 'This is my header line'
$files = Get-Childitem '<filespec>'


foreach ($file in $files)
 {
   $header | Set-Content tempfile.txt
   Get-Content $file -ReadCount 5000 |
    Add-Content tempfile.txt
   Remove-item $file
   Rename-Item tempfile.txt -NewName $file
}
```

Comment: I think this is about as good as you'll get for a pure PowerShell approach.

Comment: Solved, and it seems to be running quite fast. And -ReadCount seems to be responsible for the agility.

Comment: Minor edit was the very last item ($file.Name) wouldn't work, but it worked as only $file .

Comment: Sorry about the $file.Name. I fixed it in the answer. -ReadCount is indeed responsible for the speed.  Without that it would default to a ReadCount of 1, and it would be horribly slow.  I've seen Get-Content with the right ReadCount setting out-perform file-streaming solutions.

Comment: That is great to know. I'm curious to find out what are the factors that determine the best value for that -ReadCount. My wild guess (with little to no knowledge on the matter) would be the length of each line in that text file, and the amount of available RAM on the server. But that's just my guess.

Comment: There's probably multiple factors involved in finding the optimum read count, but basically it comes down to memory management.  If I really want to get down to fine tuning, I'll usually start with a -ReadCount of 1000, and then fire up Task Manager and start running it and increasing the ReadCount until it starts throwing page faults.and then back it off a little.